# Making an animation between states with React Transition Group, the animations overlap with each other

Tags: javascript, reactjs, animation, react-transition-group

I have a simple component with some buttons that display text: You click on each different button whenever we want to display different text and I would like to have a simple fade animation when the text switches.

What I am getting instead is a weird overlap between the two states where one appears while the other is disappearing.

This is what my original code looks like within the component:

```
export default function MyComponent() {
  const options = { option1: [OPTION1], option2: [OPTION2], option3: [OPTION3]};
  
  const [selectedOption, setSelectedOption] = React.useState("option1");

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => setSelectedOption("option1")}>Option 1</button>
      <button onClick={() => setSelectedOption("option2")}>Option 2</button>
      <button onClick={() => setSelectedOption("option3")}>Option 3</button>

      {Object.keys(options).map((option) => (
        <CSSTransition
          in={option === selectedOption}
          key={option}
          timeout={1000}
          classNames="test"
          mountOnEnter
          unmountOnExit
        >
          <div key={option} className="test">
            {options[option]}
          </div>
        </CSSTransition>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

The alternative way of getting around this is only displaying the `{options[option]}` tag within the `CSSTransition` component if it is the `selectedOption`, basically:

> {option === selectedOption && options[option]}

But with that I lose the exit animation before the next one appears. Anyway, all this to say, how could I get a transition out and a transition in smoothly between two states?

[Here is a sample of what I currently have.](https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-robinson-9ms88?file=/src/App.js:2061-2107)

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the [`delay` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition-delay) on the transition to have the "exit" and "enter" animations occur sequentially.  Each one will take half of the total duration.  "enter" will have a delay such that it won't start until the "exit" has finished.

Since only one is visible at a time it looks silly if they are stacked vertically.  We want one on top of the other.  I struggled with the jerky height and I can only get it smooth if the two options are inside of a fixed-height container.

```css
.test-container {
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
}
.test {
  position: absolute;
}
.test-enter, .test-appear {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
.test-enter-active, .test-appear-active {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1);
  transition: opacity 500ms ease-in-out 500ms, transform 1000ms;
}
.test-exit {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1);
}
.test-exit-active {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: scale(0.9);
  transition: opacity 500ms ease-in-out 0ms, transform 1000ms;
}
```

All that I changed in your JS was adding the container div.

```
<div className="test-container">
  {Object.keys(options).map((option) => (...))}
</div>
```